# Modify dplyr database query

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I'm using dplyr to execute a Redshift query via the database connection `src`. `lag` works a little bit differently in Redshift (see https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/962), so I'm wondering if it's possible to modify the query that's generated from the dplyr chain to remove the third parameter (`NULL`) in `LAG`. Example:

```
res <- tbl(src, 'table_name') %>% 
  group_by(groupid) %>%
  filter(value != lag(value)) %>%
  collect()
```

gives

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  Default
    parameter not be supported for window function lag)
```

I can see the translated sql:

```
translated <- dbplyr::translate_sql(
  tbl(src, 'table_name') %>% 
    group_by(groupid) %>%
    filter(value != lag(value)) %>%
    collect()
  )

# <SQL> COLLECT(FILTER(GROUP_BY(TBL("src", 'table_name'), "groupid"), "value" != LAG("value", 1, NULL) OVER ()))
```

And I can modify it to remove the `NULL` parameter, which I think will solve the problem:

```
sub("(LAG\\(.*), NULL), "\\1", translated)

# <SQL> COLLECT(FILTER(GROUP_BY(TBL("src", 'table_name'), "groupid"), "value" != LAG("value", 1) OVER ()))
```

How can I execute this modified query?

Comment: Since dbplyr uses RPostgreSQL as its backend driver, can't you just use  its `dbSendQuery` function?

Comment: instead of using `translate_sql` can you use `show_query` or `sql_render` ? you might be able to use the function `LAG` (upper case) directly, when the function doesn't exist in R dbplyr tries the SQL function instead.

Comment: So i'm suggesting to try`filter(value != LAG(value,1))` or `filter(value != LAG("value",1))`

Comment: Did you get this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use`DBI::dbGetQuery(con, sub("(LAG\\(.*), NULL), "\\1", translated))` to run the new query.